# IDE for ROS-Indigo, Master on Jetson TK1 (SSH Remote)

Tags: ros, ide, remote, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I wonder if anyone also uses the NVIDIA Jetson TK1 Board with Linux4Tegra ->Ubuntu 14.04 (ARM) and ros-indigo. On the Jetson TK1 itself I configured a wireless-access-point-network (ad-hoc) so after starting the board I am able to connect via SSH and so on.
ATM I use catkin build and source the devel folder like doing it for lightweight projects.
What I want instead is to use an IDE like CodeBlocks or qtCreator cause it's getting more and more code.
Hope that there will be some guys using quite a similar setup (RaPi also ARM-based). Any ideas how to make it better?

Greets

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272269/ide-for-ros-indigo,-master-on-jetson-tk1-(ssh-remote)/) by [glukon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31987/glukon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi glukon,

In the case of TK1 you can do the following (don't tell anyone I told you how to do this :P You should do it properly, see @davr answer):

1 - From your development PC open a terminal to your TK1 with X window forwarding (I assume that you configured your /etc/hosts to associate the proper IP to the hostname tegra-ubuntu):

```
ssh -X ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu
```

2 - Install qtcreator in the TK1, if you haven't done it before:

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```

3 - Execute qtcreator from the TK1:

```
qtcreator -noload Welcome 2>/dev/null 1>&2 &
```

"-noload Welcome" will skip the welcome screen of qtcreator, otherwise it will complain about OpenGL

"2>/dev/null 1>&2" will forward the console output and error output to the "null" device (so that you don't get annoying messages in your terminal)

"&" will launch qtcreator in background mode so that you can keep using the same terminal to run other commands.

This will execute qtcreator from your remote host (tegra-ubuntu) but it will be visualized in your development PC. It is note the smoothest thing in the world, but it might help you get the job done.

There might be no menu bar on the top, you can load your project with the following key combination: Ctrl+Shift+O

I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [glukon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31987/glukon/) on 2017-10-05**:
contrary to @davr this one here is a correct and nice answer. For me, davr's answer is just a short description of what he's doing. For someone asking simple questions here like me, you can assume that just a description won't help. Your answer is just perfect! Nice solution and thanks!

**Comment by [glukon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31987/glukon/) on 2017-10-05**:
After connecting to Turtlebot2 via `ssh -X` I was able to load CMakeList.txt (Ctrl+Shift+O) as mentioned in ros tutorial for using IDE's. Under 'Configure Project' I used the dafault settings and clicked on 'Configure Project'. After starting ROS-Master, I was able to run everything.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2017-10-05**:
Glad I could help. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I do is use an IDE on my development PC, where I have all the dev tools I want, plus multiple monitors etc. I play a bag with sensor data back as I am developing individual ROS nodes. When I have a working node, I transfer that code to the robot's PC. I rarely edit code directly on the robot unless it is small quick fixes, as it's more productive to work from my development PC.

---

Originally posted by [davr](https://answers.ros.org/users/32029/davr/) with karma: 46 on 2017-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3